# Where is Web Applications in ArcGIS server 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1

I'm new in using ArcGIS server 10.1 . I used ArcGIS server 9.3,9.3.1 and 10 several years.now i want to use ArcGIS server 10.1.When I install ArcGIS server 10.1, I coudln't find Web Applications tab like ArcGIS 10 or later . In ArcGIS server 10 web applications  and web services installed separately but In ArcGIS server 10.1 i just setup "ArcGIS For Server". I could create services but not Web Applications.The questions are that Where is Web Appications in ArcGIS server 10.1 ? How can i create a web application in ArcGIS 10.1 using wizard  ?

Thanks for Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the picture below, you will find the web ADF:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

The default ADF web application is not an out of the box option for v10.1.

> ArcGIS 10.1 for Server is the last release to offer the Web ADF for
>   Microsoft .NET and Java. The ADF is available through a separate
>   installation called ArcGIS Web Applications.

They suggest hosting your services via ArcGIS.com or using either [ArcGIS Silverlight or Flex viewer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_creating_web_GIS_applications/0154000004z1000000/) instead.

See also:

[Migration to ArcGIS 10.1 for Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Migration_to_ArcGIS_10_1_for_Server/0154000002p0000000/)